# render variable using Object.keys, multiple Object.keys loops reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am iterating tow object parent and child using Object.keys, I noticed Object.keys doesn't support for render, can you suggest how can i resolve this problem.

```html
Object.keys(questions).map( (key)=> {
      const  panelQuestions =questions[key];
      Object.keys(panelQuestions).map( (panelkey)=> { 
 
       tasks && tasks.map( (task, index) => {
            const QuestionSubQues = _.get(task, 'questions[0].tableRecordTemplate[0].questions', 'default');
            const questionTitle = _.find(QuestionSubQues, { 'uid': panelkey});
            console.log(questionTitle.title +' : '+ panelQuestions[panelkey]);
                           })

                      
                        });
```

I want to render questionTitle.title & panelQuestions[panelkey] variable in html display.

Answer (score 0):

```js
return Object.keys(questions).map( (key)=> {
      const  panelQuestions =questions[key];
     return  Object.keys(panelQuestions).map( (panelkey)=> { 
 
     return  tasks && tasks.map( (task, index) => {
            const QuestionSubQues = _.get(task, 'questions[0].tableRecordTemplate[0].questions', 'default');
            const questionTitle = _.find(QuestionSubQues, { 'uid': panelkey});
            console.log(questionTitle.title +' : '+ panelQuestions[panelkey]);
            return(
                    <div> <div className="abc">{questionTitle.title} :{ panelQuestions[panelkey] } </div>
                     </div> 
                           })

                      
                        });
```

need to use return keyword in each of the iteration loops